# Using underscore in Angular components

Tags: angular, underscore.js, typescript-typings

This is a simplified version of the component I'm using:

```
things: Things[] = [...]

addThing(thing: Thing) {
  // when using this.things => 'this' undefined!
}

addThings(things: Thing[]) {
  _.each(things, this.addThing);
}
```

In short, I call `addThings` which at some point calls `addThing` for each individual `thing`. What am I doing wrong? Why is `this undefined` in `addThing`?

I installed underscore in (what I think is) the usual way:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/underscore
npm install --save underscore
// angular.json:
"scripts": [
  ...,
  "node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"
]
```

Comment: I now realize I can pass `this` as a third argument to `_.each` to provide the context. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the `this` context to `_.each` like this:

```js
_.each(things, this.addThing, this);
```

Or you can use an arrow function that will bind `this` automatically:

```js
_.each(things, t => this.addThing(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also another option: make `addThing` an arrow function on its own:

```
addThing = (thing: Thing) => {
  // here we access the lexical `this`
}
```